# Java isn't getting the file in the source code when compiled

Tags: java, file, nullpointerexception, nosuchfileexception

Recently I have an issue with Java. I've tried some things I found on the web but they haven't worked, so I need help.
I have a Java project in Eclipse. My main class is in `src/programCode/UI_Main2.java`. In that `.java` I try to access to a file in `src/files/File.file`

And this is when the things fo weird.

- If I use `/src/files/File.file` it gives me `NoSuchFileException`.
- If I use `src/files/File.file` it works in Eclipse but when I compile it to a executable .jar it gives me `NoSuchFileException`.
- If I use `/files/File.file` it gives me `NoSuchFileException`.
- If I use `files/File.file` it gives me `NoSuchFileException`.
- If I use `files/File.file` it gives me`NoSuchFileException`.
- If I use `this.getClass().getResource("/files/File.file").getPath().substring(1)`  (without substring it gives me Invalid character) it gives me `NoSuchFileException` (but it shows me the absolute path and the file exists there!)
- If I use `this.getClass().getResource("files/File.file").getPath()` it gives me `NullPointerException` and the program crashes.
- If I use `this.getClass().getResource("src/files/File.file").getPath()` it gives me `NullPointerException` and the program crashes.
- If I use `this.getClass().getResource("/src/files/File.file").getPath()` it gives me `NullPointerException` and the program crashes.

So, I don't know what to do. `src/files/File.file` is the only one that works, but it doesn't when compiled to executable jar. So please, help me, I haven't found any solution yet.
Thanks!

Comment: Source code generally isn't available to compiled programs, but resources are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding a file depends on two things:

- Whether you use absolute or relative path
- Where is your working directory

Under Unix-like system when you use path like `/dir1/dir2/file` you use absolute path, so your working directory doesn't matter, but you must have a file exactly under that path.

In your case you try to use relative path, so you shouldn't use `/` at the beginning.

This case is crucial to your problem:

```
"If I use src/files/File.file it works in Eclipse but when I compile it to a executable .jar it gives me NoSuchFileException."
```

By default Eclipse uses as working directory a parent directory of `src` (which is usually a direcotry with your project", so starting from there you indeed have a file under that path.

When you start a `.jar` your working directory is somewhere else. Put your `.jar` to parent directory of `src` and it should work.

Now, I suggest that you change location of the file to a directory other than `src` (call it `Resurces` or something) and provide it along with the `.jar`.

Also, here is an interesting discussion about working directories and `.jar` files:

[Current working directory when running a Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433469/current-working-directory-when-running-a-jar)

If you want to distribute a single `.jar` here is a good packaging instruction:

http://www.cefns.nau.edu/~edo/Classes/CS477_WWW/Docs/pack_resources_in_jar.html

Comment: Thanks, it worked now! But how can I do this in a only one .jar without the folder? I compile another jar with the folder and the app jar inside?

Comment: Here is a simple instruction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096398/add-image-to-jar-java Or a more detailed one: http://www.cefns.nau.edu/~edo/Classes/CS477_WWW/Docs/pack_resources_in_jar.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your intent is to rum your compiled program on YOUR own development computer, you need to provide the full path to the file you want.  That full path would be of the form

```
<Eclipse workspace location>\<project name>\<file location in project>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use it on other computers too xD